# Joining multiple columns of 2 files in a single file

Tags: shell, file

File1 is as follows

```
1,mark,phy
2,andrew,chem
3,btet,maths
```

File2 is as follows

```
1,reg-asd-1
2,reg-fgh-2
4,reg-jkl-4
```

I want output to be as follows

```
1,mark,phy,reg-asd-1
2,andrew,chem,reg-fgh-2
3,btet,maths,
4,,,reg-jkl-4
```

I tried with following command

```
join -j 1 -t , -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2 file1 file2
```

But above command is leaving 3rd row of both file1 and file2 in output.I want these rows also in output with other fields as blank values.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. What you want is in relational database terms a full outer join, whereas `join` does an inner join by default. Change this with the `-a` option applied to both files:

```
$ join -j1 -t, -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 file1 file2                                            
1,mark,phy,reg-asd-1
2,andrew,chem,reg-fgh-2
3,btet,maths,
4,,,reg-jkl-4
```

Also note changing `1.1` to `0` in the line format; `0` is the join field, which always will have a value, unlike `1.1` or `2.1` when doing outer joins.